# Using v-memo on a list component does not work on the list items

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am trying to use v-memo directive in Vue 3 for a list of item as follows:

```
<script lang='ts' setup>
const canUpdated = ref(0)

const items = ref<any[]>([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);


const addItems = () => {
  let newItem = 1;
  const foundItem = items.value.find((item) => item === newItem);
  console.log("founditem", foundItem);
  if (!foundItem) {
 
    canUpdated.value += 1;
  }
  items.value.push(newItem);
};
</script>


<template>
   <VBtn @click="addItems">Add item</VBtn>
      <VList v-memo="[canUpdated]">
        <VListItem v-for="(number, index) in items" :key="index">{{
          number
        }}</VListItem>
      </VList>
</template>
```

When user clicks on button, i expect that, the list of items won't updated due to the newItem value has existed inside of the array list and canUpdated value is not changed.But it does not work and v-memo is not implemented correctly.
How can i solve this issue.

Comment: As `1` is already there in the items array. foundItem returns `1` and `canUpdated` value not getting updated. Also I did not understand the use of this code as you are assigning the same value in the items array again.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal, That variable can have any values, the main goal of this code, is using v-memo, and force the list to update if a new value like newItem variable is added.

Comment: In that case you have to pass items length in the array as a value for memo if you just want to see is there any new item added or not. Try this : `v-memo="[items.length]"` or `v-memo="items"` ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal, So by defining the value of v-memo such as 'items.length' the list of items don't render frequently, after mounting the component?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `v-memo` on the VListItem, not the VList:

```html
<VList>
  <VListItem
    v-for="(number, index) in items"
    v-memo="[canUpdated]"
  >{{
     number
  }}</VListItem>
</VList>
```

Putting v-memo/v-once on a component disables data binding updates, but it does not disable reactivity, so the component still updates when the slot content changes.

Interestingly enough, it does not work when you set it on both outer and inner component, it has to be just the VListItem. This is different than with regular elements like ul and li, where you can set it on either or both, even if you replace the li with a custom component. It looks like putting v-memo on a component disables it in the component's slot content.

The difference can be observed in the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const CustomListItem = {template: `<li><slot/></li>`}

const app = {
  components: {CustomListItem},
  template: `
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="pa-4 d-flex justify-space-around">
      <div>
        <VBtn @click="addItems">Add item</VBtn>
        <div>Items: {{items}}</div>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        v-once on VList (does not work)
        <VList v-once>
          <VListItem v-for="number in items">{{number}}</VListItem>
        </VList>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        v-once on VListItem (works)
        <VList>
          <VListItem v-for="number in items" v-once>{{number}}</VListItem>
        </VList>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        v-once on both (does not work)
        <VList v-once>
          <VListItem v-for="number in items" v-once>{{number}}</VListItem>
        </VList>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        v-once on ul with custom item (works)
        <ul v-once>
          <CustomListItem v-for="number in items">{{number}}</CustomListItem>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </v-main>
  </v-app>  
  `,
  setup(){
    const items = ref([1, 2, 3]);
    const addItems = () => items.value.push(items.value.length+1)
    return {items, addItems}
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```